# dynamically generated methods

Tags: javascript, date, functional-programming

found this example in Pro javascript Technique book

```
function User( name, age ) {
    var year = (new Date()).getFullYear()-age;
    this.getYearBorn = function(){
        return year;
    };
}
var user = new User( "Bob", 44 );
alert(user.getYearBorn());  //system date is 2010 ,alerts 1967
```

I changed  system date to 2012

```
alert(user.getYearBorn()); //alerts 1968.
```

based on above logic i wrote the below code

```
function Test(bornTime){
    var ageInMillis = new Date().getTime()-bornTime.getTime();
    this.age = function(){
        console.log("age:"+ageInMillis);
    }
}

var t = new Test(new Date());
t.age(); //output is zero
setTimeout(t.age,1000) // it prints 0
```

shouldn't the second call to t.age print 1000, 
am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You don't re-calculate `ageInMillis`; it will print whatever it was when you called `new`.

In order to get the behavior you expect, you need this:

```
function Test(bornTime) {
    this.age = function() {
        var ageInMillis = new Date().getTime() - bornTime.getTime();
        console.log("age:" + ageInMillis);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats what i thought , but then how come is the 1st example working

Comment: @cipher Why wouldn't it? The calculation in the first example only needs to occur once. Your example performs the calculation as well, it's just that the answer is zero, because you calculate it in the wrong place.

Comment: user.getYearBorn()  gives 1967 , since year is calculated only once invocation of this method any time should give 1967 only, but if i change the sysdate to 2012 it gives 1968( i am using testing this in firebug, changing sydate and running that line user.getYearBorn() again ). Is it because i changed sydate my date obj gets updated.

Comment: @cipher Doesn't for me; I don't see how that would be possible. The function is in a closure that binds the value of `year` made at the time `new` is executed. How are you changing the date, and under what OS?

Comment: got it, the second time user.getYearBorn() is executed the entire block function got executed again, i was selecting the user.getYearBorn() line and running it without deleting the function declaration... i guess firebug runs the entire code in its window irespective of what u have selected

Comment: @cipher Ah, yes, particularly when switching between the single- and multi-line console input will not necessarily show all that's being executed. *whew*, thought I was going crazy :)

Answer (score 2):

The ageInMillis is calculated when you do `var t=new Test(new Date());` and set as 0. Any call after that is just going to return you 0

You should change your function like below,

```
function Test(bornTime) {
  var ageInMillis; //=new Date().getTime()-bornTime.getTime();
  this.age = function() {
      ageInMillis = new Date().getTime() - bornTime.getTime();
      console.log("age:" + ageInMillis);
  }
}

var t = new Test(new Date());
t.age(); //output is zero
setTimeout(t.age, 1000); // it prints 0
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/TytrC/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing in a new Date() to Test() which is set to the current time. Then you subtract it from the current time `Date().getTime()-bornTime.getTime()` since the time elapsed was less than a millisecond, the difference is 0 millis.

When you call it the second time after one second has elapsed, the variable hasn't changed. You would need to redo the subtraction in the "dynamic method" (it's actually called an anonymous function in JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

your variable is being set when you create the object.  it is then the same value for all time.  if you want it to change you should make it a function.  your code is actually working though, its just that you are getting the current time and subtracting the current time from it.  change the date you pass in.

```
var ageInMillis=function() {
    Date().getTime()-bornTime.getTime()
};
```

Comment: Without further context, I don't get how this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's look at what you're doing.

```
var t=new Test(new Date());
```

Okay, so you're creating a new object with the `bornTime` being now.

```
var ageInMillis=new Date().getTime()-bornTime.getTime();
```

`bornTime` is now, and you're subtracting it from now. Any number subtracted from the same number is zero, so... I think your problem is obvious now ;)

Comment: Not really; while what you say is true, it doesn't address the true nature of the problem.